# I accidentally changed ownership of sudo to current administrative user

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

After running the (stupid) command :

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

Having `$(npm config get prefix)` being equal to `/usr`, I have changed the ownership of `/usr/bin/sudo` to my administrative user. Now when I try to `sudo` I get the following error :

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

It was a fresh Ubuntu installation so I don't mind reinstalling but if there is another way I'm in. Note that I had not set a password for `root` so I believe I have no way to login as `root`. If I could it would be great, I would just `chown -R root:root /usr/bin` and it would fix my problem.

My `/etc/` folder is still owned by `root` and everything works fine except `sudo` giving the above error message.

Comment: Please re-install easiest that way since its a new install!

Comment: @Zanna thank you for the link but these are 2 very different issues. I'm not talking about `/etc` but `/usr`, my principal problem is that `/usr/bin/sudo` is now owned by another user than `root`

Comment: the principle is the same. There's lots of stuff in `/usr` and you ran with the `-R` flag. `sudo` doesn't work if you `chown` `/etc`. Use this procedure and replace `/etc` with `/usr` in the commands

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB, mount your disk on /mnt.  Now change the ownership of  /mnt/usr/bin/sudo. Reboot the machine, see if sudo is error free now.

Comment: I agree with WillemK as one needs to have experience with using LiveCD systems to fix all sorts of stupid things we (or others) do.

Comment: WillemK's suggestion is incomplete. Fixing ownership of `/usr/bin/sudo` is not enough. And obviously the linked post suggests booting a live session, because there's no other way to fix it